# Bounty Programs for Open Source Projects

Tags: data-request, programming, software, open-source

I am interested in data that contains bounties or paid rewards for specific programming tasks in open source projects.  Ideally, the data would contain a description of the task, the amount of the bounty, task status (e.g. open, in progress, complete, etc.), and a link to task homepage or public repository.  I'd also like to distinguish between bug bounty programs typically offered by private firms and platforms that price issues in public respositories (e.g. Gitcoin, IssueHunt, BountiesNetwork).  I am interested in both but I would prefer OSS bounty platforms.

Answer (score 3):

I've compiled a short list of potential sources to answer the question:

- https://www.freelancer.com/
- https://www.bountysource.com/
- https://www.bounties.network/
- https://internetbugbounty.org/
- https://gitcoin.co/
- https://issuehunt.io/
- https://whitehub.net/
- https://www.boss.dev/

Any other suggestions, edits, or comments welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know up to which extend the spirit of the original answer by @sboysel is preserved by including the fees with a link to the source for the fees, so I posted it as a separate answer:

- https://www.freelancer.com/feesandcharges?w=f&ngsw-bypass=#
  max(3%,$3)
- [www.bountysource.com/fees](http://www.bountysource.com/fees)
  Free, but withdrawel costs 10%
- https://www.bounties.network/
  website not available (for me)
- https://internetbugbounty.org/charter.html
  Appears to be free (it is sponsored)
- https://gitcoin.co/legal/terms
  10 %
- https://issuehunt.io/terms
  10 %
- https://whitehub.net/ -> https://cystack.net/en/terms
  4.1: Costs are obfuscated as an unspecified function of what one has to "pay to purchase service packages"
- https://www.boss.dev/policies#privacy
  Obfuscated as: "a flat fee (“Flat Fee”), a percentage of the Listing price (“Commission”)"